# Using a variable on JavaScript to a status from one button

Tags: javascript

I'm using a variable to change a status of a button color. When I change the color first time, I'll not change in second click:

```
function Status(){
    var flag = 0;
    if(flag == 0){
        flag = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        flag = 0;
        return 1;
    }  
}

$("#lampada1").click(function() {
    if (Status() == 0) {
        $("#lampada1").removeClass("botaoVermelho").addClass("botaoVerde");
    }
    if (Status() == 1) {
        $("#lampada1").removeClass("botaoVerde").addClass("botaoVermelho");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `flag` variable in global scope or it will be always 0 inside `Status()` :

```
var flag = 0;

function Status(){
    if(flag == 0){
        flag = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        flag = 0;
        return 1;
    }  
}
$("#lampada1").click(function() {
    if (Status() == 0) {
        $("#lampada1").removeClass("botaoVermelho").addClass("botaoVerde");
    }
    if (Status() == 1) {
        $("#lampada1").removeClass("botaoVerde").addClass("botaoVermelho");   
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** It will be better to use **[`toggleclass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** instead of `addClass/removeClass`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#lampada1").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("botaoVermelho botaoVerde");
});
```

```css
.botaoVermelho{
    background-color: green;
}

.botaoVerde{
    background-color: red;
}

#lampada1{
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='lampada1' class="botaoVermelho">Lampda 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this like this:

```
$("#lampada1").click( event => $(event.target).toggleClass("botaoVerde botaoVermelho") );
```

You don't even really need two classes, the last class applied will work (although it's more readable and less fragile if you use two)

```js
$("#lampada1").click( event => $(event.target).toggleClass("botaoVermelho") )
```

```css
.botaoVerde { color: green }
.botaoVermelho { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="botaoVerde botaoVermelho" type="button" id="lampada1">half a button</button>
```